# Setting Listview <li> Height in jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, button, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to resize the `<li>`s in my jQuery mobile site (listview) and can't seem to find the right class in CSS to do it. I've basically resized some of the elements (the header and footer, etc.). I have five `<li>` buttons stacked vertically and there is a gap below the buttons and the footer.

I just want to set each `<li>`'s height to 20% (that would do the trick since there is five of them and they are nested in a body content div. Does anyone know the class in the jQuery Mobile CSS that controls this? I can't seem to find this info in a search. Here's a link to the CSS for reference:

[jQuery Mobile Default CSS](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.css)

Thanks!

### UPDATE

I was originally meaning to discuss 'listview' exclusively for the buttons. I was too broad in my original explanation but basically I'm trying to resize not all buttons but just the `<li>`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check-out the classes you can make your own decision about how to select the `LI` elements, I would use the `.ui-li` class and if you want to make sure to only get one `listview` element then you can specify a more detailed selector:

```
#my-listview-id > .ui-li {
    height : 20%;
}
```

Here is some sample `listview` output from the jQuery Mobile docs:

```
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-f ui-corner-top ui-btn-up-undefined">Overview</li>
                <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="docs/about/intro.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>
                <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="docs/about/getting-started.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Quick start guide</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>  
                <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="docs/about/features.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Features</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>
                <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="docs/about/accessibility.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Accessibility</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>
                <li data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-corner-bottom ui-btn-up-c"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li" aria-hidden="true"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="docs/about/platforms.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Supported platforms</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>
            </ul>
```

**UPDATE**

There was a little more to this than I had previously posted, here is some tested/working code:

```
#my-page {
    height   : 100%;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}
#my-page .ui-content, #my-listview {
    min-height : 100%;
    height     : 100%;
    margin     : 0;
    padding    : 0;
}
#my-listview .ui-li {
    height : 20%;
}
```

Where `#my-page` is the id of my `data-role="page"` element and `#my-listview` is the id of the `data-role="listview"` element.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gu7WE/

Comment: Ah, perfect. I was forgetting to set the .ui-content class before trying to adjust the <li>.

Comment: The `.ui-content` class should automatically applied by the jQuery Mobile framework. You can also target the same element by attribute: `[data-role="content"]`

Answer (score 0):

`.ui-btn` is the class you have to use.But this same class is used not just by "buttons" alone .Other jQuery Mobile components like `listview` also make use of it.So if you set the height of `.ui-btn` you will mess up those components too.So it is better to define a separate class,only for those five buttons and then set the `height` to `20%` to that class.

Comment: Are you saying define a div class like <div class="button"><li>Test</li></div> and then in the CSS something like .button {height:20% width:80%}; or whatever I want? I just tried it and I think I'm doing something wrong in that regard...

Comment: I just updated my question, I realized I was too broad in my original explanation. I am referring to <li>s not buttons. Sorry about the confusion!

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? This would do the trick too IMHO.

```
#my-listview-id {
   height:100%;
}
#my-listview-id li {
    height: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as that:

```
.ui-li>.ui-btn-inner {
  padding-top: 10px
  padding-bottom: 10px
}
```