# change height of li in jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, html-lists

I am trying to change the height of a li element but with no luck. I have tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838212/setting-listview-li-height-in-jquery-mobile) but its just not working! I am working with jQM version 1.1.1. The listview is being generated dynamically. The following is the code:

```
$('.eventInfoBox').append(' <div id="eventInfoBoxContents"> \
   <div data-role="fieldcontain"> \
      <label>Target Item: </label> \
      <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="targetItemUL">\
          <li class="ui-li"><img style="width:20px;height:20px;margin-top: 3px;margin-left: 3px;" id="targetImage" src="images/products.jpg" /> \
             <div style="padding-left: 5px;"> \
                <h3>Testing</h3> \
             </div> \
          </li> \
     </ul> \
   </div> \
').trigger('create');
```

The CSS I've added is as follows:

```
#targetItemUL > li .ui-li {
    height : 30px;
}
```

Could someone help me out here and tell me what is that I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: can you copy code to jsfiddle so we can update their as per you need?

Comment: Here is a link to the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ares05/jMEPc/1/ I can't seem to reduce the size of that li.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jMEPc/2/ I edit it have a look

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see a change in your fiddle. There has been no change of code. The height of the LI is still default value and not re-sized to 30px. Kindly check the link.

Comment: if you inspect from Chrome or firebug with FireFox you will see change of height http://i45.tinypic.com/10n954k.jpg have a look to it or you can change height for getting better result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the problem! Arpit took your suggestion and inspected using firebug. The problem was the min-height property. It was set at 60px by jQM css and had to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` *is* `.ui-li`, but your current selector looks for a `.ui-li` element *inside* the LI. Change

```
#targetItemUL > li .ui-li
```

to

```
#targetItemUL > li.ui-li
```

Comment: No that didn't work unfortunately :( I've added a fiddle in the above comment. Kindly have a look.